# Python - Stock trading backtesting simulation without .itterows()

Tags: python, dataframe

Here is the simplified sample dataset:

```
   Price Signal
0    1.5       
1    2.0    Buy
2    2.1       
3    2.2       
4    1.7   Sell
```

Here is the code to generate the above sample dataset for ease of reference:

```
price = [1.5, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 1.7]
signal = ['', 'Buy', '', '', 'Sell']
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(price,signal), columns = ['Price', 'Signal'])
```

**Here is the task:**
Assuming initial cash = 100 and stock position = 0, simulate cash and stock position at each step based on the following code using .itterows()

```
cash = 100
num_of_shares = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if row['Signal'] == 'Sell':
      if num_of_shares > 0:
        cash = num_of_shares * row['Price']
        num_of_shares = 0
  elif row['Signal'] == 'Buy':
    if cash > 0:
      num_of_shares = cash / row['Price']
      cash = 0
  df.loc[index, 'Position'] = num_of_shares
  df.loc[index, 'Cash'] = cash
```

**Here is the result:**

```
   Price Signal  Position   Cash
0    1.5              0.0  100.0
1    2.0    Buy      50.0    0.0
2    2.1             50.0    0.0
3    2.2             50.0    0.0
4    1.7   Sell       0.0   85.0
```

**Here is the Question: Is there any way to achieve the result faster than using .itterows()?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use. to_dict() function in Pandas to convert the data frame to a dictionary. Now iterating over a dictionary is comparatively very fast compared to iterrows() function. Iterating over a dictionary format of the dataset takes about 25 records that is 77x times faster than the iterrows() function.

for example:
iterate dataframe with iterrows()

```
for key,value in df.iterrows()
    # key is your index
    # and value is your row
```

iterate dataframe after converting to dictionary

```
dict1 = df.to_dict(orient='index')
for key in dict1:
    value = dict1[key]
    #key is your index
    #value is your row
```

if we compare dataframe and dictionary, suppose my dataframe has 3400 rows
if i use pandas iterrows() it will take 2.45 sec to iterate full dataframe
in case of dictionary for the same length it will take 0.13 sec.

so converting pandas dataframe to dictionary its always good practice and best way to optimize the code.